# Shiny - sliderInput with hours

Tags: r, shiny, hour

I am trying to program a sliderInput with hours and the code is:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
      sliderInput("hour", "Range",
                  value = c(as.POSIXct("00:00",format = "%H:%M"),
                            as.POSIXct("23:59",format = "%H:%M")),
                  min = as.POSIXct("00:00",format = "%H:%M"),
                  max = as.POSIXct("23:59",format = "%H:%M"))
)
```

However, the slider does not show a 24hr format.
How can I do it?

I have tried also by entering the date:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
      sliderInput("hora", "Range",
                  value = c(as.POSIXct("01/01/15 00:00"),
                            as.POSIXct("01/31/15 23:59")),
                  min = as.POSIXct("01/01/15 00:00"),
                  max = as.POSIXct("01/31/15 23:59"))
)
```

How could be this fixed?

Comment: Where are you going to use this sliderinput? Have you tried making it a vector of c(0:23) and then converting it to as.POSIXct at the point where it will be used? Would be easier for the slider to interpret a simple vector.

Comment: @bstrain As I'll use a dataset which contains this dates, I think a vector won't be the best way to solve it, don't you think so? I'll the shinyapp like a way to select a bike a certain day and time. Do you think this would work also? Thanks for your suggestion in any case.

Comment: Shiny supports dates but not times (I think). If I were you I'd use a slider to get a value between 0:23 and combine it with a date from a date select, as shown here https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/date-and-date-range.html and convert to POSIXct. You can format the ticks on the slider to look like times so the user doesn't know the difference.